# Setting of custom filter for customer and order grid in Admin

Tags: custom-options, admin-panel, magento2.1.6

we have more than 3000 customers on site and we need to to display particular records. I am setting the custom count under per page drop down but it will take 999 max, how can i make it custom filter count.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you want to achieve here I personally don't think its a good Idea. The process may take a longer time to load or may even stuck depending on server specs.

Although If you still want to do this. Magento sets a **min** and **max** value where you can set in for custom listing.

[sizes.js](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/grid/paging/sizes.js)

```
/**
 * Converts provided value to a number and puts
 * it in range between 'minSize' and 'maxSize' properties.
 *
 * @param {(Number|String)} value - Value to be normalized.
 * @returns {Number}
 */
normalize: function (value) {
    value = +value;

    if (isNaN(value)) {
        return this.getFirst();
    }

    return utils.inRange(Math.round(value), this.minSize, this.maxSize);
}
```

So the above function will check the range and if it exceeds the range it will return the maxSize

So you need to change the maxSize in order to get the range you want.

```
return Element.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'ui/grid/paging/sizes',
            value: 20,
            minSize: 1,
            maxSize: 999, // You need to change this value
            options: {
                '20': {
                    value: 20,
                    label: 20
                },
                '50': {
                    value: 50,
                    label: 50
                },
                '100': {
                    value: 100,
                    label: 100
                },
                '200': {
                    value: 200,
                    label: 200
                }
            },
            statefull: {
                options: true,
                value: true
            },
            listens: {
                value: 'onValueChange',
                options: 'onSizesChange'
            }
        },
```

Recommend not to change the core file you can override it. Make sure to deploy static content after you make changes.

Comment: I have shared the git source. You can get that file in dir `<magento_dir>/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/grid/paging/sizes.js`